# Azure Authorization: what is scope parameter in REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rbac

I am creating a Azure custom role for blob storage access.

I started with Azure cli, and when I convert the json file to Terraform file, there is an extra parameter, `scope`.

It appears that it is the `scope` parameter in [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-definitions/create-or-update#uri-parameters), controls where the role is defined (subscription, tenant or deeper).

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Value for your `scope` parameter would depend on the level at which the role is defined. It could be one of the following values:

- **`subscriptions/{subscriptionId}`**: Custom role is scoped at a subscription level.
- **`subscriptions/{subscriptionId1}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup1}`**: Custom role is scoped at a resource group level.
- **`subscriptions/{subscriptionId1}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup1}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{site1}`**: Custom role is scoped at a resource level.
- **`providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/{groupId1}`**: Custom role is scoped at a management group level.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-rest#list-custom-roles-at-a-scope

Comment: Cool, thank you! Apparently the section I mentioned is out of sync with this one.